# Azure Service Bus Message Lock

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Suppose in an Azure Bus which is working in Peek-Lock Mode there is a default lock period of 30 Seconds.

**Does this mean that if a message entered lock in period , then during the lock period next message is also not available to other consumers?**

**Does a deferred Message is available to other consumers or is it moved to separate queue?**

Comment: `Does a deferred Message is available to other consumers or is it moved to separate queue?` - Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: In peek-Lock Mode during message settlement ,a message can deferred. If the message is deferred ,is it placed in the same queue or in a separate queue? Is the deferred message is available to other consumers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that if a message entered lock in period , then during
> the lock period next message is also not available to other consumers?

No, only the message that has been locked is not available to other consumers.

> Does a deferred Message is available to other consumers or is it moved
> to separate queue?

The deferred message remains in the same queue and will not be available to any consumer. From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-deferral):

> When a queue or subscription client receives a message that it's
> willing to process, but the processing isn't currently possible
> because of special circumstances, it has the option of "deferring"
> retrieval of the message to a later point. **The message remains in the
> queue or subscription, but it's set aside.**

Comment: Since queue is FIFO,
Let say I have retrieved a message and the message is locked.
Till the acknowledge(Complete API) is received from consumer the queue retains the message.
During the lock period as it says next message is available for consuming
and lets think the second message is retrieved & processed fastly and acknowledge(complete API) is received
but consumer1 sends an abandon message.
Is this case a violation of FIFO working style?

Comment: It is still FIFO. You just need to look from the perspective of Service Bus and not your application.